# Using polygon contains

Tags: java, polygon, contains

I have a problem with [`Polygon#contains(Point)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains(java.awt.Point)). I am testing if a point is inside the polygon.

This is how the `Polygon` is constructed:

```java
Polygon p = new Polygon(new int[]{300, 300, 500, 500}, new int[]{200, 400, 400, 200}, 4);
```

For the vertex `(300,400)`, the output is `false`, which is what I want:

```java
System.out.println(p.contains(new Point(300,400))); //prints "false"
```

However, for the first vertex (`(300,200)`), it prints `true`:

```java
System.out.println(p.contains(new Point(300,200))); // prints "true"
```

Based on the first statement, it should print `false` as well.

Why are the results different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange behavior. It can be the case, that some of the special cases from the [definition of insideness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#def_insideness) (see below, copied from the documentation) are observed. Another exlanation might be the precision of double values.

> Definition of insideness: A point is considered to lie inside a Shape if and only if:
>
> - it lies completely inside theShape boundary or
> - it lies exactly on the Shape boundary and the space immediately adjacent to the point in the increasing X direction is entirely inside the boundary or
> - it lies exactly on a horizontal boundary segment and the space immediately adjacent to the point in the increasing Y direction is inside the boundary.

The point (300, 400) lies on a horizontal boundary, but the space immediately adjacent in direction Y is not inside the boundary = > contains will return false.

The point (300, 200) however, lies on the horizontal boundary ( also on the shape boundary) and the spaces immediately adjacent to it in Y and X directions are inside the boundary => contains will return true.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, though this isn't related to double precision at all - as you indicate, it's due to the definition of "inside" which (to oversimplify) includes the top and left edges, but excludes bottom and right edges.